# Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../../../../../lib/craftcms-sass/mixins

Tags: permissions, css, files, filesystem

I have two Craft websites running locally and they both have broken css on the backend due to the error below. Every time I update it is temporarily fixed but after a few clicks or refreshes it's back again. I've checked the permissions but the problem seems to be the location of the file.

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../../../../../lib/craftcms-sass/mixins
```

When opening the dashboard.scss I can see the path is incorrect but I'm very unsure what the proper path should be, and whether I should manually change it.

Is this a known problem? I hope someone here can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out my file watcher (WebStorm) was the cause.
It compiled the dashboard.scss, so I simply changed the Scope to make sure it only compiled my own files.